# Define number of handled key events per second Android

Tags: android, keyboard, keylistener

I need to limit number of key events handled per second.
The idea is, because in my app users can use keyboard.
When user hold down on right navigation button, for example.
I don't want to handle every event, because my app can get stucked in calculation loop.
And then force close, wait dialog appears.

I want to handle 2,3 events per second and other just to ignore.
So I can add little cool down time for the app and calculation thread.

Is is possible?
I think I must use some timers or simple sleep function in my key listener, but I can't figure out right way to do this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be doing some time comparison when you receive a key event:

```
// a variable in your class:
private long mPreviousKeyEventTime = 0;

// in the key event handling function:
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - mPreviousKeyEventTime < 300) return;
mPreviousKeyEventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

300 is the time in milliseconds - change it to suite your needs.

Edit: if the keyboard is also used for typing, then make these restrictions only when navigating.